# Writing a vector of struct with flatbuffers

Tags: python, flatbuffers

I have the following classes:

namespace Message;

```
struct BBox {
 xmin:float;
 xmax:float;
 ymin:float;
 ymax:float;
}

table msg {
  key:string;
  boxes: [BBox];
}

root_type Message;
```

To create the object I do something such as

```
b = flatbuffers.Builder(0)
msg.msgStart(b)
msg.msgAddKey(b, b.CreateString(key))

v = flatbuffers.Builder(0)
size = len(boxes)
msg.msgBoxesVector(v, size)
for elem in boxes:
    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = elem
    BBox.CreateBBox(v, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
boxes = v.EndVector(size)
msg.msgAddBoxes(b, boxes)
obj = msg.msgEnd(b)
b.Finish(obj)
```

and no error is thrown

However when I try to display the results, the key is good but the size of the vector and the content is wrong

```
rep = msg.msg.GetRootAsmsg(bytearray(b.Output()), 0)
print rep.BoxesLength()  # give me 4 instead of 1 
for i in range(rep.BoxesLength()):
    print rep.Boxes(i).Xmin(),  rep.Boxes(i).Ymin()
    print rep.Boxes(i).Xmax(),  rep.Boxes(i).Ymax()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have an open issue about the Python port not doing enough error checking: https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/299

The creation of the string and the vector should happen before `msgStart`. also, you should use just one Builder object (use just `b`, not `v`), since the above code refers from one buffer to another, which won't work.

EDIT: the Python implementation now correctly signals an error when you try to nest vector/string/table generation. It still can't detect cross-buffer offsets however.

Answer (score 3):

I will give what I've done, hoping it may help other people (based on Aardappel answer)

```
b = flatbuffers.Builder(0)

if boxes:
    boxesOffsets = 0
    msg.msgStartBoxesVector(b, len(boxes))
    for elem in boxes:
        xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = elem
        BBox.CreateBBox(b, float(xmin), float(xmax), float(ymin), float(ymax))
    boxesOffsets = b.EndVector(len(boxes))

msg.msgStart(b)
msg.msgAddKey(b, b.CreateString(key))
msg.msgAddUrl(b, b.CreateString(url))
msg.msgAddCountry(b, b.CreateString(country))
msg.msgAddLimit(b, limit)

if boxes:
    msg.msgAddBoxes(b, boxesOffsets)

obj = msg.msgEnd(b)
b.Finish(obj)
```